# Are there any Google's Products / Services, where I can ask for refund, if a person is not satisfied?

Tags: google, web-services, pricing

Are there any  Google's Products / Services, where I can ask for refund, if a person is not satisfied?

I want to use google services as I feel, google is required for running any business?

Comment: Most google services are free except adwords. If you want to use google Apps, that's another question. Please clarify.

Comment: I am asking about Google's paid services. Take Google's advertising   program and paid business solutions for instance.

Comment: So it's google Apps and google adWords...

Comment: It's based on voting with your dollars. If the paid services don't work, quit using them and go elsewere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the google Apps TOS, there's only 1 occurrence for the word refund, and that's about google terminating the contract, so no. There's no refund if the customer is not satisfied.
Also for goole Apps, there's a 30 day trial period, which you can use to evaluate the quality of the services google provides for the business. Also, if the number of google Apps users are lower than 5, the services can be used free of charge.

As for google AdWords, the success of the advertising is defined by two factors. The person managing the ad campaigns (how much he/she knows about the tool, and on-line advertising), and how much money are you willing to spend on the campaign. There's no refund for an unsuccessful campaign. The success of the campaign can be measured through conversion and/or the number of visitors to the company website.